# Dynamics CRM 2015 Import values

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise version.

Im importing my solution to an other organization with custom entities and workflows.

I created a workflow to do some work depending on the type of the inserted queueitem.

My issue: Some conditions in my imported workflow are not supported in the new organisation (only the conditions on the custom entities are not supported and are replaced by empty brackets)

I think the custom entities IDs are not imported with the same values, so, the CRM does not recognize these custom entities condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exporting and importing the customization in two separate solutions.

In the first solution include the entities and optionsets you wish to import. Export the solution from the old environment, import into the the new environment and publish.

In the second solution include the workflows. Oncce again export the solution from the old environment, import into the the new environment and publish.

Answer (score 0):

When you point to an entity inside a workflow, it will retain the GUID.

If you export/import the workflow, the reference will be lost because that specific GUID won't exist in the new environment.

Comment: What do you suggest to resolve this? I'm trying to separate the solution like Kevin Hendricks says

Comment: The only workable solution I found (and use) is to never have lookups and check record fields instead (that makes sense to me in a way: instead of checking "if X is this exact record" I'd check "does X contain Y inside that field?")

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed that the GUID values of the records referenced in your workflows are passed trough the solution but doesn't exist in your target environment.

You can either:

- Modify you workflows, instead of (for example) `Primary Entity Opportunity / Account / Equals / Contoso` use `Related Entity Account / Account Number / Equals / ContosoNumber`
- Import the data referenced in your workflows by keeping the same GUIDs. This is slightly more technical:

  - First, you need to export the data from your source organization (either SQL or Export to Excel with reimport enabled)
  - Then convert this file to csv while keeping the id value embeded
  - Reimport the file with import wizard and mapping the GUID column